# How to redirect system.out.print statements to web page in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, stdout

I hava written System.out.print statements in my java code within JSP page. I want to redirect all my sysout statments on webpage. It it possible?

Comment: first of all show us some code of your jsp page. currently your question is realy unclear.

Comment: you can use `out.println` to print data from JSP to  webpage.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this instead of System.out.print:
`PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print(smt);`